# Script repeat itself after X minutes

Tags: bash, loops

I have a bash script in Ubuntu, I want it to run every 10 minutes for example after it's done. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can check `watch`.
From [the man pages of `watch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) the description says `watch - execute a program periodically, showing output fullscreen`, you can try `watch -n 600 my_script.sh` which will execute `myscript.sh` every 600 seconds i.e. 10 minutes. `watch` shows the output to full screen, you can redirect it to say `/dev/null` in case you are not interested in the output to the screen.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Cronjobs is what you need.

My blog post:- http://linux-junky.blogspot.com/2010/10/guide-to-add-cronjob-simplified.html

Or you can also use **sleep 600** in your script.

Comment: Okay I can sleep it, how about to just rerun the script after sleep?

Comment: Just use cronjobs. `sleep` and `at` loops is a decision that you should not make.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`at`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at) to reschedule the script from within the script. At the end of the script put:

```
at now + 10 minutes << END
"$0" "$@"
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with crontab -e, or another option, to check the date. for example, if you want to do something every 10 minutes, you can write:

```
if [ $((`date +%M`%10)) -eq 0 ] && [ `date +%S` -lt 10 ]; then
   #your code
fi
```